# Different SSL certificates show up when running openssl inside the application container as compared to port forwarding from my client machine

Tags: ssl, azure-aks

I have a service setup on Kubernetes running inside a pod. The service is running on port 27018.

If I ssh into the pod and run this command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mydomain.io -connect localhost:
27018 </dev/null
```

It shows a valid certificate.

However if I port-forward this container and run the same command from my client machine

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mydomain.io -connect localhost:
27018 </dev/null
```

It shows an expired certificate. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When doing a port forward you are getting the local host certificate, most probably the certificate of the apiserver fronting the port-forward + the local server that kubectl creates.

Do you have a certificate that allows for localhost to be an accepted host name ?

Keep in mind that you are taking to a service on https://localhost , your application might not be configured to accept such source.

Comment: I thought the ` -servername ` parameter allows SNI testing